# Replace words in file 2, getting the list of replacements from file 1

Tags: scripts, text-processing

Cat File 1

```
ABC,23
DFG,45
Ghj,678
```

Cat File2

```
Listed LinkedIn yellow ABC
Fixed DFG linked ABC
Holiday Europe Ghj DFG
```

I need the output as below

```
Listed LinkedIn yellow 23
Fixed 45 linked 23
Holiday Europe 678 45
```

Comment: Do you have any line like this `Holiday Europe DFGhj` or `Holiday Europe DFGGhj` ?

Comment: No ... The last line is Holiday Europe Ghj DFG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `bash` associative arrays.

```bsh
$ cat foo.txt  # Contents of "foo.txt"
ABC,23
DFG,45
Ghj,678

$ cat bar.txt  # Contents of "bar.txt"
Listed LinkedIn yellow ABC
Fixed DFG linked ABC
Holiday Europe Ghj DFG

$ declare -A foobar  # Declaring associative array "foobar"

## Putting comma separated portions of file "foo.txt" as key-value 
## pair for array "foobar"
$ while IFS=',' read a b; do foobar["$a"]="$b"; done <foo.txt 


## Now reading each line of "bar.txt" and iterating over the keys 
## of array "foobar" by "${!foobar[@]}" to find a match, if found
## correspoding value of the key will replace the key using parameter
## expansion pattern "${line//key/value}"

$ while IFS=' ' read line; do for i in "${!foobar[@]}"; do \
    line="${line//"$i"/"${foobar["$i"]}"}"; done; echo "$line"; done <bar.txt 

Listed LinkedIn yellow 23
Fixed 45 linked 23
Holiday Europe 678 45
```

Here is the expanded version of the last portion :

```bsh
while IFS=' ' read line; do 
    for i in "${!foobar[@]}"; do 
        line="${line//"$i"/"${foobar["$i"]}"}" 
    done 
    echo "$line" 
done <bar.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Transform `file1` into commands for `sed` and use them to modify `file2`:

```
sed -r 's/(.*),(.*)/s,\1,\2,/' file1 | sed -f - file2
```

This assumes that the values in `file1` don't contain special characters and you want to replace all occurrences in `file2`.

Comment: That's a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`

```
awk 'FS="," {\
    if(NR == FNR) {\
        n[(FNR"")] = $0\
    } else {\
        a[($1)] = $2\
    }\
}\
END {\
    for (i in n) {\
        for (j in a) {\
            gsub(j,a[j],n[i])\
        }\
        print n[i]\
    }\
}' File2 File1
```

---

*Example*

The input files

`cat foo`

```
ABC,23
DFG,45
Ghj,678
```

`cat bar`

```
Listed LinkedIn yellow ABC
Fixed DFG linked ABC
Holiday Europe Ghj DFG
```

The command and the output

```
% awk 'FS="," { if(NR == FNR) {n[(FNR"")] = $0} else {a[($1)] = $2}}  END {for (i in n) {for (j in a) {gsub(j,a[j],n[i])} print n[i]}}' bar foo
Listed LinkedIn yellow 23
Fixed 45 linked 23
Holiday Europe 678 45
```